# OrientDB integration with Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Am trying to integrate OrientDb 2.1.6 with Kerberos, but couldn't find any  documentation about it. need to clarify

1) OrientDB 2.1.6 supports Kerberos

2) Any one has implemented it already.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Kerberos Plugin so far, but it's in OrientDB roadmap.